# Let $E$ be a normed space, $(X,d)$ a metric space and $A \subset E$ a convex bounded set. Show that $f(A)$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $E$ be a normed space, $(X,d)$ a metric space and  $A \subset E$ a convex bounded set. Let $f : A \to X$ be uniformly continuous. Show that $f(A)$ is bounded.

I'm trying to find the right definitions to use here. If $A$ is bounded then for every $x,y \in A$ we have that $[x,y] \in A$. Also  if $A$ is bounded then $d(A) = \sup\{d(x,y) \mid x,y \in A \} < \infty$. So  what I want to show is that $d(f(A)) = \sup\{d(x,y), \mid x,y \in f(A) \} < \infty$? I'm not sure what I should do with the fact that $A$ is convex? From uniform continuity I get that all close points stay close to each other, but not sure that is of help?

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Fix a point $x_0\in A$. Then we have for all $x\in A$ and all $N\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$
$$ d(f(x_0), f(x)) \leq \sum_{j=1}^N d\left( f(x_0+\frac{j-1}{N}(x-x_0)), f(x_0+\frac{j}{N}(x-x_0)) \right).$$
Now use the fact that $\vert x -x_0 \vert \leq C<\infty$ and the uniform continuity to get an estimate for $N$ sufficiently large.

Here I used the convexity to connect $x_0$ to $x$ by a straight line, which lies completely in $A$.

For general bounded sets this will not work. Take $E=\ell^2(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$ and $A= \{ e_j : \ j\in \mathbb{N} \}$, where $e_j=(0, \dots, 0, 1, 0, \dots)$ (the $1$ is the $j$th entry). Then any map is uniformly continuous (simply, because $\Vert e_j - e_k\Vert = \sqrt{2}$ for $j\neq k$). Clearly there are unbounded maps $f: A \rightarrow X$ if $X$ is unbounded (pick your favourite one to get a counterexample). Note that this is kind of the easiest example one can get as for finite dimensional normed spaces we have that bounded & closed sets are compact. In that setting we can continuously extend $f$ to the closure of $A$, however, as continous functions map compact sets to compact sets and in metric spaces compact sets are bounded, we get that $f(A) \subseteq f(\overline{A})$ is bounded.

Comment: +1 Nice answer!

Comment: How exactly did you get the RHS for the inequality $d(f(x_0), f(x)) \leq \sum_{j=1}^N d\left( f(x_0+\frac{j-1}{N}x), f(x_0+\frac{j}{N}x) \right)$?

Comment: By convexity don't we have that for every $x,y \in A$ we have that $\lambda x(1- \lambda)y \in A$, where $\lambda \in [0,1]$?

Comment: By the triangle inequality we have $d(a,b) \leq d(a,c)+d(c,b)$. I iterated the the triangle inequality to get that sum. I took the line $\{ x_0 + t x \ : \ t\in [0,1] \}$ and chopped it into $N$ intervals of the same length (namely $\Vert x -x_0\Vert /N$).

Comment: To address your second comment: I guess you mean $\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y\in A$? Note that we can rewrite this as $y+ \lambda(x-y)$, then you get my claim.

Comment: So if I understood correctly $d(f(x_0), f(x)) \leq \sum_{j=1}^N d\left( f(x_0+\frac{j-1}{N}x), f(x_0+\frac{j}{N}x) \right)$ is saying that for a fixed $x_0 \in A$ the image of $f(x_0)$ and any other point $f(x)$ is less than or equal to the sum of the $N$ segments connecting these two points? I feel slightly confused about the fact that we need to fix some $x_0$.

Comment: A set being bounded means that the distant to a fixed point (I called mine $x_0$) is bounded. Is that fine?

Comment: The point here is that for some fixed $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $N$ (large enough) such that for all $x$ (that is the crucial point) we have $$ d\left( f(x_0+ \frac{j-1}{N}(x-x_0)), f(x_0+\frac{j}{N}(x-x_0) \right) <\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the summation here if I want to break up a segment to $N$ intervals I have that $\frac{|x-x_0|}{N}$. Where does the $x_0$ and $\frac{j-1}{N}$ leading terms come from?

Comment: I suggest you try to do an example (a picture surely helps). Take $E=\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the segment that connects $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$. Next, what do you need to change to get the partition of the segment $(1,0)$ to $(2,1)$?

Comment: Shift by $(1,0)$ the segment connecting $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$?

Comment: Exactly, this is what adding the $x_0$ does.

Comment: I'm grateful for your patience with me, but I'm not sure how the example is related to the problem, the segments $(0,0), (1,1)$ and $(1,0), (2,1)$ are not part of the same line?

Comment: You want to split the segment from $x_0$ to $x$ into $N$ segments of the same length. If $x_0=0$, then you take the vector $x$ and divide it by $N$ for the first segment (this means the endpoint of the first of the small segments is $\frac{1}{N}x$). Now you start from $\frac{1}{N}x$ and add the same portion again (so the endpoint of the second segment is $\frac{2}{N}x$). Hence, the $j$th segment starts at $\frac{j-1}{N}x$ and ends at $\frac{j}{N}x$. If you want to do do the same thing starting from $x_0$, then you can translate this segment first (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Then you consider the segment from $0$ to $x-x_0$. Thus, the points of the segments are $0, \frac{1}{N}(x-x_0), \dots, \frac{N-1}{N} (x-x_0), x-x_0$. So to recover the segments we really want, we have to add back $x_0$. So the points we really want are $x_0, x_0+ \frac{1}{N}(x-x_0), \dots, x_0+ \frac{N-1}{N}(x-x_0), x_0+ (x-x_0) =x$. Is it clear now? Just draw a picture, it sounds much more complicated than it is.

Comment: I see! It is clear now. Now it seems that I just need to look at $$\|x_0+ \frac{j-1}{N}(x-x_0) - (x_0+\frac{j}{N}(x-x_0)) \|$$ and find the sufficient $N$ from here.

Comment: Exacty, and this reduces to $\frac{\vert x -x_0\Vert}{N}$ which is convenient to estimate :)

Comment: So $N > \frac{\|x-x_0\|}{\delta} = \frac{C}{\delta}$. Do you happen to know if there is a full proof somewhere online I could take a look? I didn't find this particular problem here anywhere nor googling around.

Comment: Full proof of what? The estimate you wrote is not quite good enough as your $N$ would still depend on $x$, which is exactly what you want to avoid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123308/discussion-between-ralph-and-severin-schraven).